# Criteria with composite-id error

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, criteria

NHibernate.
I have 3 tables:

Employee {**PK:EmployeeId**, Name, LastName, ...}

Project {**PK: ProjectId**, date, name, ...}

EmployeebyProject {**PK:FK: EmployeeId, ProjectId**, date, ...}

I need make some CRUD, at this moment I have some records in the tabla EmployeebyProject. So I'm try to Get someone of this records. This is the method using criteria, but happend this error: "GenericADOException, could not execute the query" "Column EmployeeId is not valid", "Column ProductId is not valid". **The problem with this criteria is not go to Employee and Project tables to make the query for the idEmployee, and idProject.**
So how can I make this??.

```
 public EmployeebyProject GetEmployeebyProjectByIdEmployee(int idEmployee, int idProject)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
            {
                var employeebyProject = session
                        .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmployeebyProject))
                        .CreateCriteria("Employee", "Employee")
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EmployeeId", idEmployee))
                        .UniqueResult<EmployeebyProject>();
                return employeebyProject;
            }
        }
```

this is the mapping for EmployeebyProject:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AdminProject"
                   namespace="AdminProject.Business.Entity">

  <class name="EmployeebyProject">

    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Employee" column="EmployeeId"  class="Employee"></key-many-to-one>
      <key-many-to-one name="Project" column="ProjectId"  class="Project" ></key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id> 

    <property name="DateBegin" type="DateTime"/>
    <property name="DateEnd" type="DateTime"/>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: can you try `var employeebyProject = session
                        .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmployeebyProject))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Employee", session.Load<Employee>(idEmployee)))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Project", session.Load<Employee>(idProject)))
                        .UniqueResult<EmployeebyProject>();`

Answer (score 0):

the EmployeeId property you are calling from `.Add(Restrictions.Eq("EmployeeId", idEmployee))` is wrong, the EmployeeId does not belong to the EmployeeProject entity. It belongs to the Employee entity. So your query should be rewritten as

```
    public EmployeebyProject GetEmployeebyProjectByIdEmployee(int idEmployee, int idProject)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
        {
            var employeebyProject = session
                    .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmployeebyProject))
                    .CreateCriteria("Employee", "EmployeeAl")
                    .CreateCriteria("Project", "ProjectAl")
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EmployeeAl.id", idEmployee))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ProjectAl.id", idProject))
                    .UniqueResult<EmployeebyProject>();
            return employeebyProject;
        }
    }
```

and i think that instead of `.CreateCriteria("Employee", "EmployeeAl")` you should call `.CreateAlias("Employee", "EmployeeAl")` and the same for the project